# why is dpkg configuration running out of space on ubuntu 10.04 when there is space available?

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

There is 7Gb available but...

```
~ # dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae (2.6.32-31.61) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-31-generic-pae

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-31-generic-pae
Failed to create initrd image.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 2.6.32.31.37); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae
 linux-image-generic-pae
 linux-generic-pae
~ # df
Filesystem           1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             18577148  10255512   7377972  59% /
none                   1026416       164   1026252   1% /dev
none                   1030624         0   1030624   0% /dev/shm
none                   1030624       100   1030524   1% /var/run
none                   1030624         4   1030620   1% /var/lock
none                   1030624         0   1030624   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1                93207     87960       435 100% /boot
~ # cat /etc/redhat-release
cat: /etc/redhat-release: No such file or directory
~ # cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-30-generic-pae (buildd@vernadsky) (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) ) #59-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 23:01:33 UTC 2011
~ # uname -a
Linux ws1.naturapet.com.au 2.6.32-30-generic-pae #59-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 23:01:33 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
~ # lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but it might be because you're trying to update your kernel image.  If you notice, you have about 400k left in your boot partition and it might be trying to copy there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your /boot partition is 100% full.  New linux kernels will be installed there, but they obviously cannot be if that partition is full.

Check whether you have old kernels installed and uninstall them.

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

will tell you which linux kernels you have installed.

```
uname -a
```

will tell you what kernel you are currently using.

Comment: http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/ was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

cause you have no space left on /boot